# updating a database using SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite

i am trying to edit a record from my database by letting the user select what they want to edit within that record.

i get the following error

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Type' referenced before assignment
```

my code is as following:

```
import sqlite3
def update_data(values):
    with sqlite3.connect("mrsimms.db")as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        sql = "Update Stock set Type=?,RetailPrice=?, NumberInStock=? where Name=?"
        cursor.execute(sql,values)
        db.commit()

def update():
  Update = "y"
  while Update == "y":
      Name = input("Please enter the name of the product you wish to update: ")
      Type_change=input('would you like to edit the type?(y/n) ')
      if Type_change == 'y':
          Type=input("Please enter the updated type: ")

      RetailPrice_change=input('would you like to edit the retail price?(y/n) ')
      if RetailPrice_change=='y':
          RetailPrice = input("Please enter the updated retail price: ")

      NumberInStock_change=input('would you like to edit the number in stock?(y/n) ')
      if NumberInStock_change=='y':
          NumberInStock = input("Please enter the updated number in stock: ")

      data = (Type,RetailPrice,NumberInStock)       
      update_data(data)
      Update = input("Do you wish to update another lesson? (y/n) ")
      print()
update()
```

thank you :)

Comment: And? What is your problem?

Comment: sorry - i get the error UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Type' referenced before assignment

Comment: OK, so think through your code logically. What is the value of `Type` when you call `update_data` if the user has not input "y" to edit the type?

Comment: The problem has nothing to with sqlite, by the way.

Comment: Hint: Variable names start with a lower case letter in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You have this code.

```
if Type_change == 'y':
    Type=input("Please enter the updated type: ")
```

There is no `else` and `Type` is not assigned to later.

So here

```
data = (Type,RetailPrice,NumberInStock)
```

`Type` dos not exist if the `if`condition was not true.

Add an `else` clause or initialize `Type` outside the `if`.

Comment: do you know the code to keep 'Type' what it is in the database so its not updated?

Comment: `sql = "Update Stock set RetailPrice=?, NumberInStock=? where Name=?` and only use `(RetailPrice, NumberInStock)` as data.